# passing id to the url for the authenticated user when they login

Tags: php, laravel, url

Am following some code and every time it tries to show posts for users it passes the user id to the url manually like "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/1".
How can this be done without typing in the url

#### Home.blade.php

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
                <div class="col-4">
                    <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" class="w-30" alt="">
                </div>
```

#### route

```
Route::get('/home/{user}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

#### HomeController

```
  public function index(User $user)
{
  //

  return view('home', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: I am clear to your problem. What do you want actually?

Comment: i am getting to this url  http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/1 by typing manually and i want this to be done just when the user logs in or when they click a button. i only know how to do it without the variable in the route like Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use like this

```
<a href="{{ url('') }}/home/{{$user->id}}"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{route('home',['user'=>$user->id])}}"></a>
```

Here you can get idea how to pass variable.

Comment: I am really happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to redirect the user after login you can modify the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware in `app/http/middleware`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->route('home',array('user' => $request->user()));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The id was passed to the url in this manner

```
    $user = Auth::guard('web')->id();

            return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The user is redirected to the home page with their id upon login in in the following way

### login controller

```
  */
protected function redirectTo()
  {
 $user = Auth::guard('web')->id();


    return route('home',['user'=>$user]);
   
   }
```

### note

The route to the home controller should have the variable 'user'

```
Route::get('/user/{user}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```